# Declare attributes of library module which can be modified by app

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create Android library module (API 21+) for my application, which will implement some of the business logic shared across various applications.
The issue is that I want to declare attributes in this library module, for which I will be able to set values in app modules of aforementioned projects.

The funny thing is, that my current solution works on emulator but not on physical devices.

Here is how I have it now (simplified, irrelevant parts omitted):

Library's attrs.xml:

```
<resources>
    <attr name="lib_Background" format="reference"/>
    <attr name="lib_Logo" format="reference"/>
</resources>
```

Applications styles.xml:

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="lib_Background">@drawable/back</item>
    <item name="lib_Logo">@drawable/logo</item>
 </style>
```

It does not matter whether I try to access these resources from xml of library's layout like this:

```
<ImageView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:src="?attr/lib_Background"
   android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
```

or programatically like this:

```
fun Context.getDrawableFromAttributes(idOfAttribute: Int): Drawable? {
    val a = this.theme.obtainStyledAttributes(intArrayOf(idOfAttribute))
    val resourceId = a.getResourceId(0, 0)
    a.recycle()
    return this.resources.getDrawable(resourceId, this.theme)
}
```

Still I have this image properly loaded on emulator, but "null" on physical device.

Is there some better or correct way how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have kinda forgot about this question.

The issue was that I have used broken PNG for one particular density which caused it to be null. So it was not and error in implementation at all and this approach is absolutely valid.